# How the macro func and function func can be distinguished without any ambiguity?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
int func(int, int);
#define func(x,y) x/y+x
int main()
{
    int i, j;

    scanf("%d", &i);
    scanf("%d", &j);

    printf("%d ", func(i + j, 3));
    printf("%d\n", func(i + j, 3));

}

int func(int x, int y) {
    return y / x + y;
}
```

What should be added to this code so that the 1st output is the result of the macro and the 2nd one is the result of the function?

Comment: A proper name? maybe.

Comment: You should not! I repeat **not!** do this, because there is no way to distinguish a function or a macro

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Comment: your title could as well be "How to make a function call impossible to distinguish from a macro call?". I mean you can make the compiler distinguish but for anybody else reading the code it will definitlely be a major source of confusion

Comment: This is a question from a quiz of some kind, so there's no point in suggesting alternatives to the macro. It's like responding to "why did the chicken cross the road" with a lecture on road safety and how everyone should be a vegan, like you.

Comment: Does not compile live: https://godbolt.org/z/CL7MR8  So no _"...ambiguity..."_ to resolve.

Comment: For the record, C standard library functions are allowed to be defined with both a macro and a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several ways:

```
printf("%d ", func(i + j, 3)); // Macro call
#undef func // Macro is no longer defined
printf("%d\n", func(i + j, 3)); // Function call
```

or

```
printf("%d ", func(i + j, 3)); // Macro call
printf("%d\n", (func)(i + j, 3)); // Function call
```

Comment: The first version is the only answer that will work, as the code will not compile otherwise.

Comment: @dbush: only because definition of function `func` is done after the MACRO, and then broken by the MACRO. But can be fixed by moving definition before the MACRO, or use `int (func)(int x, int y) {
    return y / x + y;
}` is the same manner as function call.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
#define EMPTY

printf("%d\n", func EMPTY (i + j, 3));
```

Seen in Boost.PP, the `EMPTY` macro "burns up" the expansion iteration and the resulting `func(...)` is left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is

```
printf("%d\n", (&func)(i + j, 3));
```

`(&func)` takes the address of the function `func`. Since it doesn't have the form `func()` there's no macro substitution done. Since function pointers can be called, the behavior is as intended.

Comment: This is basically `(func)(i + j, 3)` from Jarod42's answer, but with 1 more character. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I realized that when I saw it appear under Jarod's answer, but I then considered that my answer had an explanation why it works.